# How to maximize recall in multilabel setting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I have a text classification problem in which I want to assign one of three labels (-1, 0, 1) to text documents. The most important metric is recall: I care that all texts that should be labelled "-1" are indeed labelled "-1". The precision, that everything that is labelled "-1" is indeed labelled "-1", is less important.

So far, I am using a pipeline in scikit-learn with logistic regression. The hyperparameters are tuned in GridSearchCV, but so far, accuracy is maximized.

```
steps = [('vect', CountVectorizer()),
      ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), 
      ('clf', LogisticRegression())]

parameters = {'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)],
           'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
           'clf__C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],}

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
text_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv = 5)

text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = text_clf.predict(X_test)

scores = cross_val_score(text_clf, X_test, y_test, cv = 5)
```

Changing

```
text_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, scoring = 'recall', cv = 5)
```

does not work because it is a multiclass setting. Does anybody have an idea how I could reformulate this in order to maximise recall?

Comment: This problem is a _multiclass_ problem, not a _multilabel_ problem. Multilabel is the case which each example might have more than one class related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid-search can work if only a single number is presented by the metric as score which GridSearchCV will use to order the results.

In case of multi-label setting, you need to decide which type of averaging you want there for different labels. You can use the following alternatives:

```
scoring = 'recall_micro'
scoring = 'recall_macro'
scoring = 'recall_weighted'
scoring = 'recall_samples'
```

For the description of these, please refer to [documentation of recall_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html#sklearn.metrics.recall_score):

> ```
> average : string, [None, ‘binary’ (default), ‘micro’, ‘macro’, ‘samples’, ‘weighted’]
>
>     This parameter is required for multiclass/multilabel targets. 
>     If None, the scores for each class are returned. Otherwise, this
>     determines the type of averaging performed on the data:
>
>     'binary':
>         Only report results for the class specified by pos_label. 
>         This is applicable only if targets (y_{true,pred}) are binary.
>
>     'micro':
>         Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, 
>         false negatives and false positives.
>
>     'macro':
>         Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. 
>         This does not take label imbalance into account.
>
>     'weighted':
>         Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average, weighted 
>         by support (the number of true instances for each label).
>         This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in
>         an F-score that is not between precision and recall.
>
>     'samples':
>         Calculate metrics for each instance, and find their average 
>         (only meaningful for multilabel classification where this
>         differs from accuracy_score).
> ```